# How to change MATLAB Surf plot Color Map?

Tags: matlab-figure

A surf plot has the default color scheme:

[image]

I would like to change the color of 'face of the cliff' to:

- facecolor = green  for faces for 10 < Z < 20
- facecolor = yellow for faces for 20 < Z < 30
- facecolor = red    for faces for 30 < Z < 40

How is this done? (with a color map?)  A reference (link)  to the MATLAB documentation \ example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?